# boost shared_ptr and derived class

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have such a code:

```
class Base { ... };

class Derived : public Base
{ ... };

boost:shared_ptr<Base> p;

int main()
{
  p(new Derived);
 ...
}
```

It seems to me that this isn't working.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing in class initialization with assignment. The member-initializer list syntax only works inside of the class body:

```
p = boost::make_shared<Derived>();
```

Comment: I almost added "or I'll do it myself" :D